# Is it possible to find(generically) an object with a GUID in a nested Class in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have nested classes ie

**Order**

```
ID, (GUID = 8e6e48f7-9047-4e2a-95e7-ec4318641fbb)
Date
Orders -> List<OrderItem>
```

**OrderItem**

```
ID, (GUID= = 4582234b-d8b5-4665-b00f-e4f09ff3e2c6)
ProductId
Qty
Unit
Price
ID, (GUID= = b0d12322-e92c-42c6-b2b7-520db1d3a818)
ProductId
Qty
Unit
Price
```

Because I have nesting and I am using GUIDs as IDs for my objects, I am wondering whether there is a generic method to find an object given a GUID. One I have this object I could then remove it from it parent list.

By the way, I do realise that I could used specific lambda expression to get at the specific objects, but this would result in many expressions for many different scenarios, hence many interest in one generic approach.

Thanks,

Comment: Do these nested classes have any kind of common base or implementation?

Comment: No, apart from they are all distinct classes, but the master ones reference some other detail classes via List Properties. For background I am creating this nested structure from deserialized XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably create an interface that all of my classes (or base classes) would implement called `IGuidSearchable` or something like that. It would need to set two properties, the ID and a `Children` collection of `List<ISearchable>`. The implementing classes could either use this or would be responsible for setting this property to be equal to the property they use (like `Orders -> List<OrderItem>` in your example).

```
public static IGuidSearchable FindObjectByGuid(this IGuidSearchable source, System.Guid guid) 
{
    if (source.ID.Equals(guid)) 
    {
        return source;
    }
    foreach (ISearchable child in source.Children)
    {
        if (child.FindObjectByGuid(guid) != null)
            return child;            
    }   

    return null; // Fall through    
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks. So, just to confirm, there is nothing "out of the box" that one could use to search a nested list?

Comment: @EdB no, because the code must know two things: your classes contain an ID which you want to search for and your parent class contains a child collection that should also be searched. You can do this using reflection, but that's just an antipattern. Use an interface or base class like suggested here.

Comment: OK, thanks for this. How deeper nesting affect the suggestion above. So if my structure was now Documents > Orders > OrderItems, and I wished to search for a specific OrderItem object from the top level object(Documents MyDocument).

Comment: @EdB: As long as each class implements the `IGuidSearchable` it should nest ad infinitum (which may be bad if you have exceptionally deep/wide lists). @CodeCaster: Thanks, I hadn't had time to look at responses yet :)

Comment: @JoelEtherton, Thanks for this, really appreciated. I am just thinking around the issue, and wondering what would happen if the upper level just contained a single object (not lists), so the structure could be MySingleDocument > MySingleOrderObject > MyOrderItemList. I will using this concept in other work, and can see this situation arising. Sorry to be awkward.

Comment: This is a great answer, so I am marking it as such, so thanks. However I am also interested to see if one can take a LINQ approach. At the very least one can specify a LINQ to Objects query using the specific classes which is not great for me. So I am creating a new question focussing on this approach. I will then have 2 options. Huge thanks again.

Comment: Could I create another Partial Class definition that implements this interface, and thus protecting this one when the other partial class is regenerated?

Comment: You could, but I think you would gain much more by having an abstract class from which ALL of your class trees inherit that implements the actual ID and collection of children.

Comment: @JoelEtherton, Excellent advice, thanks, ie Create "DocumentMaster" which is inherited by Document, with the former implementing the searchable interface. So many ways to do things. Thanks.